# How to prompt user to save email into a specific drive folder in .msg format after sending it in OL2003?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want the user to be prompt for saving the email in .msg format into some network folders after the has been sent.

So in fact he clicks "Send", the mail is sent and after that he's prompt for saving it. If he cancels nothing happens, the mail is sent anyway.

VBA scripting?

Comment: Do you want the message file to be saved to the hard drive instead of a folder location within Outlook?

Comment: Yes, not a hard drive but a network drive, but it's almost the same subject. I know how to make it with OL folder. Thank you !

Comment: BUT the message will be save in the meantime in the normal Sent items folder in OL.